# Calculating AVG for NULL values from all previous rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns like this: `EmployeeID, Date, StartTime, EndTime`. First two columns are not nullable, but others 2 are.

I want to generate a report and fill the missing StartTime and EndTime with AVG value of the previous rows. I'm using the following statement for the StartTime column:

```
ISNULL([StartTime], DATEADD(SECOND, AVG([dbo].[GetTimeInSecondsFromDateTime]([StartTime])) OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID] ORDER BY [Date]), [Date]))
```

The problem is, when i have 2 NULL values one after another, they get the same value (AVG from all the previous ones) and what i need is: in the calculation for the second NULL value, the previous one to be included too (which is calculated) ... the thing is, i have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: how many rows do you have?

Comment: Post sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not tested. I Hope it helps

Because of the null values, I suggest you to first Update By StartTime

```
UPDATE t1
SET StartTime = ISNULL(StartTime, t2.AvgStartTime)
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   EmployeeID, 
   Date, 
   Avg(StartTime) OVER(ORDER BY Date Asc) As AvgStartTime,
  FROM yourTAble 
) t2 ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
Where 
  t1.StartTime is null
```

then for endTime

```
UPDATE t1
SET EndTime = ISNULL(EndTime, t2.AvgEndTime)
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
   EmployeeID, 
   Date, 
   Avg(EndTime) OVER(ORDER BY Date Asc) As AvgEndTime,
  FROM yourTAble 
) t2 ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID
Where 
  t1.EndTime is null
```

Comment: Actually, mathematically if I have a array of integers [3,6,9,12], the AVG will be 7.5. But also AVG from [3,6,9,12,7.5] is 7.5 again ... so yea the partitioning actually works.